# fetch gmail email without imap extensions in php

Tags: php

Is there a way to get the google emails using php but without the imap extension?

Comment: you could write your own POP3 client layer...

Comment: @SirDarius: there isn't enough of those already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sure](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_IMAP)

> PEAR's Net_IMAP Provides an implementation of the
>   IMAP4Rev1 protocol using PEAR's
>   Net_Socket and the optional Auth_SASL
>   class.

To clarify, this is a package that implements the IMAP protocol in PHP code, instead of requiring an extension to be installed. It will probably not perform as well as the C-client would, but it should be functional at least.

Comment: Thanks. Its ok, i just need to fetch

Answer (score 2):

Weeell, you *could* use a POP3 client class, like this one: http://pecl.php.net/package/POP3 - but it will be a huge hassle. POP3 is a very rudimentary protocol, and IIRC you need to specifically allow it for the given GMail inbox. It is possible though, if you really can't go with IMAP.

Comment: Thanks. But i would go with the pear imap.